# GeoCoordinateWatcher only fires the initial time and no longer responds

Tags: c#, geocoding

I'm trying to get the lat/lon of the device. Here is my code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Create the watcher.
  Watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

  // Catch the StatusChanged event.
  Watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;

  // Start the watcher.
  Watcher.Start();
}

private void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
  {
    // Display the latitude and longitude.
    if (Watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Unknown latitude and longitude.");
    }
    else
    {
      GeoCoordinate location = Watcher.Position.Location;
      MessageBox.Show($"Lat: {location.Latitude} Long: {location.Longitude}");
    }
  }
}
```

When I click the button to fire the event is the only time I'm getting a lat/lon reading. The event is not firing again, I put a break point on it, unless I click the button again. Am I misunderstanding how this code should work? Shouldn't it fire off any time that the lat/lon changes?

Comment: I suspect you want to subscribe to `PositionChanged` as well as `StatusChanged`...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the response, I've added that event. The only way I could get it to fire was to add a timer and fire the `Watcher.Start();` every time I want coordinates.

Comment: I would suggest logging *all* StatusChanged events, and also noting the MovementThreshold property.